# Centre location not updating, puts me in the middle of the ocean?

Tags: mkmapview

Stuck on something very basic, just started up with MKMapView and trying to get it to zoom in on my location.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate; }
```

This code seems to just not be working, I understand it usually takes a little bit of time to get the location and i have left it for a while with now luck. However the location shows up correctly but it doesn't centre in on this (it centres into the very middle of the map just off west africa)

I also have the following code in viewDidLoad, which seems to be correct as it zooms in to the specified height, just not place.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 20000, 20000);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

EDIT: It seems to be working on the simulator now after pressing back once or twice and then re-viewing to the map. But it doesn't work on my iPhone still. I have checked all the location services settings and they seem to be all on.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to set center and span to be shown in MapView. It should work.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0,0},{.5,.5}}; 
region.center.latitude = doubleLattitude;
region.center.longitude = doubleLongitude;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

If a MKMapView centers to just west of Gabon, it's very likely that one of your objects is nil and thus the coordinate is 0° latitude and 0° longitude. You can easily test it by setting a breakpoint in the debugger and analyzing your objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;
```

Does not center map on user location.
 `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` is called only first time when device gets user location,
 better use - `(void)locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:  fromLocation:`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {



    if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy>0)
    {
    // set center of map (span will not be changed in this case)
    [mymap setCenterCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate animated:YES];

    // or use region to specify both span and center
    MKCoordinateRegion region.span.latitudeDelta = .05 ;
         region.span.longitudeDelta = .05 ;
         region.center.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude ;
         region.center.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude ;
            [mymap setRegion:region animated:TRUE];

    }
     }
```

Comment: Not true, - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation IS called when the user location changes.